# Unable to install software-properties-common for Docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

To install Docker I need to run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
```

which requires `software-properties-common`.

When I try to install `software-properties-common` with `sudo apt-get install`, the following error occurs:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 software-properties-common : Depends: python3-software-properties (= 0.96.20.9) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So then I try to install `python3-software-properties` and this shows:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-software-properties : Depends: python3-pycurl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And if I try to install `python3-pycurl`:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-pycurl : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So does this mean my Python version has to be <3.6 ? This seems to be really weird. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Had you tried doing  `sudo apt-get update` ?

Comment: Yes, `sudo apt-get upgrade` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the sources in my `sources.list` were broken. Previously I was using Aliyun's sources (since I'm located in China) which caused the errors above. Switching to Tsinghua's sources fixed the issue.